# .net Interop in windows 7 with VB6

Tags: .net, windows-7, vb6, interop

I've got a legacy VB6 DLL that I've modified to take advantage of DirectShow when on Windows 7, due to WIA not working well in Win7 for cam capture.

I've incorporated a .NET DLL into the vb6 DLL that has functions to provide information and one function to display forms for the DirectShow capture stuff.

The DLL functions as expected on the development XP box and a test client XP machine, but I'm having difficulty with Win7.

I've registered the DLLs, ran `gacutil`, and set it up just like I did for the XP machine, but I'm getting automation errors.

> Error Description: Automation error
>
> Error Source: bvImgCap
>
> Module: clsMain
>
> Procedure: CaptureGraphic

This particular Win7 machine happens to be the development platform for the .NET DLL, and it runs fine by itself.

Comment: I don't understand this error description.  Are you having problems connecting to your .Net dll or is the error something that happens in whatever function you are calling?

Comment: Fancy showing some code? An opaque error message isn't particular useful.

Comment: I can put some up when I get a chance, but it seems that this is only happening on my development win7 box. It works fine on win7 machines that haven't touched any of these DLLs.

Answer (score 0):

"Automation error" points to an error in resolving the proper Net dll's. This may be caused by the fact that the Net Framweworks (1.1., 3(.5),4.0) on the XP machine may not be the same as the Win7 box. Alternatively the file structure of the Net dll's is wrong and some dll's cannot be found.
I have had good results by using [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to troubleshoot these issues.